# Django custom user model, with unique togethr - tenant and username

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-users

I am making a multi tenant app on Django, where I want the user model to be unique together on "tenant" (foreign key to tenant model,having the tenant details) and "username", ie something like - unique_together =("username", "tenant") or any of its variety. Is there any possibility of doing that?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You probably want to make the email unique too (if you're adding emails).

Comment: Thanxxx Francois!!! I'm trying this but not working. Lets say username A, with tenant A is already registered. I'm trying another username A, with tenant B try to register...django is not accepting. My user model is derived from AbstractUser, where I've put this constraint of unique together.Oncw this works out, i'll do the same with email as well.

Comment: username most likely has a unique constraint, so you cannot add username A twice. One workaround would be to have the relationship as many to many, and add the constraint on the through table

Comment: Karthikr, how can the many-to-many table help me get username with A registered twice? Because, you see, one user with username A is different from another user with username A. So I dont think many-to-many will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django user model need "username" to be unique, therefore I will suggest to use another field to replace the username such as "email" which i believe you want to keep unique

In order to do that you need to override the user model and change the username field

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

Comment: is there no hack, with which I could override this username constraint?. The other option I'm having is to autogenerate username. Lets say tenant name is A, usernames would be autogenerates as A1, A2...etc. But this is the last preferred option I need.

Comment: Im sorry but no, you need to create custom user model which inherits AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

Comment: Use this:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-proxy-models

Comment: Was not willing to do it!!! But now, it seems I'll have to do just that...thanks segalle!!!